# Extra space coming while copying records from SQL Server 2014 to Excel

Tags: parsing, sql-server-2014, copy-paste, excel-2013

I'm using SQL Server 2014, and every week I have to execute one big select query and copy those results to Excel 2013. But while copying, extra spaces are being inserted for one column so I can't get the exact format to Excel.

Screen shots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqRUa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiEma.png)

This is split query:

```
Select top 1 
    substring (text, charindex('sets: ', text) + 6, 40) 
from 
    di_log 
where 
    infonum = 6 
    and text like 'Finished reading%Sx33%' 

union all 

select top 1 
    substring (text, charindex('sets: ', text) + 6, 40) 
from 
    di_log 
where 
    infonum = 6 
    and text like 'Finished reading%Sx33%'
```

When I execute on SQL Server 2012, I didn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce this. Are you sure your query results don't include the extra spaces?

Download the latest version of SQL Management Studio from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms and try it again.

Comment: Yes, i'm getting extra empty line while pasting the result in Excel. you can find the attached screen shot for this